# Need help to convert the date time into EST in apex class

Tags: apex, datetime

I have googled it but no proper solution I found it in any salesforce community.

Scenario is we are making a callout and getting the response as string value like `"2018-06-12T19:00:00-07:00"`. Now tricky part here is to convert into EST date time and update the record into salesforce.

Can any one please help on this ASAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code should get you the date time in EST:

```
String datetimeStr = '2018-06-12T19:00:00-07:00';
System.debug('=======datetimeStr=' + datetimeStr);

Datetime datetimeGMT = (Datetime)Json.deserialize('"' + datetimeStr + '"', 
Datetime.class);
System.debug('=======datetimeGMT=' + datetimeGMT);

String datetimeESTStr = datetimeGMT.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ', 'EST');
System.debug('=======datetimeESTStr=' + datetimeESTStr);
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! You made my day ....thank you very much @Bhoopender

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.valueOf('2018-06-12T19:00:00-07:00');`

or Datetime.valueOf('...'); but in this case you have to format it the correct way.

Alternatively you can deserialize the string and create a date with

Datetime.newInstance(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds);

Comment: We will get error as invalid date time format